# Consolidated Counter and Counters per thread Multithreading in C#

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to implement multithreading for processing a huge volume by using Parallel for each. For maintaining counters, what will be the best approach?

What I would need is:
Thread 1 executed 100 records
Thread 2 executed 200 records
Total 300 got processed

Because, I have a logic in place inside parallel for each which puts the row into data table and at the end of each 10K records per batch, I need to push to database and reset the counter. So I need to ensure that, per thread, once 10K records are reached, I should push to database.

I tried using  Interlocked.Increment(ref cnt) but it only gives me running counter i.e. 300 in above example. How do I get 100 and 200 per thread ?

Please bear with my terminology, I am new to this.